# Ehresmann's lemma/ Ehresmann's Fibration Theorem Reference

Tags: differential-topology

I'm required to use Ehresmann's Lemma in a project to prove that something is a locally trivial fibration but I'm struggling to find a good reference for the theorem - i.e. it's stated nicely on Wikipedia etc but I can't find it in a book written in English. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try Voisin's Hodge Theory book.

Comment: I think a wonderful reference is Dundas book: A Short Course on Differential Topology.